# Combine of signed and unsigned bytes

Tags: c

I need to copy 3 variables into 1 variable using `memcpy`. Only the first data is copied into payload memory? I have a combination of signed and unsigned variable

[image]

```
int8_t payload[7] = {0};
volatile int8_t data1;  //1 byte signed integer 
volatile int16_t data2;  //2 byte signed integer 
volatile uint32_t data3;  //4 byte unsigned integer 


int main() {

    
        data1 = 0x7F;
        data2 = 0x7FFF;
        data3 = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            
        memcpy(payload,  (void*)&data1, 1);
        memcpy(payload+1, (void*)&data2, 2);
        memcpy(payload+2, (void*)&data3, 4);

    
    return 0;
}
```

**Update!!!**
Here is the modified/fixed version.
I had to change the  `int8_t payload[7]` to `uint8_t payload[7]`  to fix the overflow
and my mistake `memcpy(payload+2, (void*)&data3, 4)` to `memcpy(payload+1+2, (void*)&data3, 4)`

```
uint8_t payload[7] = {0};
volatile int8_t data1;  //1 byte signed integer 
volatile int16_t data2;  //2 byte signed integer 
volatile uint32_t data3;  //4 byte unsigned integer 


int main() {

    
        data1 = 0x7F;
        data2 = 0x7FFF;
        data3 = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            
        memcpy(payload,  (void*)&data1, 1);
        memcpy(payload+1, (void*)&data2, 2);
        memcpy(payload+3, (void*)&data3, 4);

    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `payload+2` So if you copied 1 byte, then 2 bytes, then... should be `+3`. `Only the first data is copied into payload memory?` How do you check that?

Comment: "Only the first data is copied into payload memory?" Is that a question or an observation? What is in `payload` at the end? When you check content of `payload` do you take endianess into account?

Comment: @ KamilCuk well spotted  payload+2+1

Comment: @ Gerhardh I have added a screenshot of my output result

Comment: @User6996 you should have debugged it and looked at your result after each step, or print results after each step [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Tve3rqcan)

Comment: How exactly does it make sense to use signed 8 bit integers as payload? Why aren't they unsigned?

Comment: This strongly smells like an XY-problem. What is your REAL problem?

Comment: That screenshot clearly shows that 6 bytes are copied. How is this *only the first data*? Taking endianess into account, the `7F` of second value that was located at index 2 was overwritten by the third `memcpy` call.

Comment: When responding to some comment, please do not add a space between `@` and the name you want to address. Otherwise no notification is sent to the user.

Comment: @Gerhardh see the screenshot data1 = 7f and data2 =7fff not data2 =ffff

Comment: Note: Casting away `volatile` is a very bad idea. If variable is declared with volatile qualifier for a good reason, then you should not access it through non-qualified pointer, like `memcpy` does. On the other hand, if non-qualified access is safe, then why are variables `volatile` qualified in the first place?

Comment: @user694733  I have volatile for debugging only. eventually wil remove the unnecessary functions

Comment: You must read my comments completely. I stated that the `0x7F` was overwritten by third data. In memory `data2` is `0xFF 0x7F` (note my hints towards endianess). If you start `data3` too early you put the first `0xFF` from `data3` into that position. That said, your test case is not suitable to test anything. First of all you should check the memory after each call to `memcpy` to see what is going on. Secondly, you should use data that you can recognize. Make `data1=0x11; data2=0x2233; data3=0x44556677;` Then try again. If you test something, design your tests to create conclusive results.

Comment: @Gerhardh Correct. I do agree with the first part of your comment. 0x7 is where i recognize the beginning of every variable. payload had to be unsigned instead of signed because if data1=0x11 and data2=0x2233 maybe the output was ok with smaller size value but not with the bigger values

Comment: No, changing `payload` to `uint8_t` would not change anything. `memcpy` does not care about the type of the destination memory area. No sign extension or other things will happen. It just copies the bytes from one location to the other. This will become more obvious as soon as you don't use that many `0xFF` values that you might interprete incorrectly as the result of some sign extension. If you insist on using larger values, use `0xF0`, `0xF1F2`, `0xF3F4F5F6`.

Comment: Instead of "magic numbers" you should use named constants for indices and sizes. Proper code will look something like `memcpy(&payload[INDEX_DATA2], &data2, sizeof data2);`. You shouldn't use `volatile`, you shouldn't use casts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
memcpy(payload,  &data1, sizeof data1);
memcpy(payload + sizeof data1, &data2, sizeof data2);
memcpy(payload + sizeof data2 + sizeof data1, &data3, sizeof data3);
```

Do however note that this method might cause problems. For instance if you're sending the data to a machine with different endianess.

Comment: this is what i already have except 'memcpy(payload + sizeof data2 '. I still have the same result

Comment: @User6996 Are you saying that my code is the same as yours, if you ignore the differences?

Comment: @User6996 there is no `memcpy(payload + sizeof data2` in that code. And also not in your code. It is `memcpy(payload + sizeof data2 + sizeof data1` So basically, if you don't fix, you still get the error

Comment: @klutt yes i do 'sizeof data1 = 1' and 'sizeof data2 = 2' and 'sizeof data3 = 4'

Comment: @klutt. I actually did run your code just to be sure. that in case I miscalculated sizes